# Should I start from scratch to learn iOS on iOS 6? What about the old 'Good' learning material?

Tags: ios, ios6

I want to learn to program on iOS and what I've found out is that the best books recommended in Amazon and other discussion websites belong to older iOS versions. My questions are:

- Are there such dramatic changes in iOS 6 (as like what happened in Java SE 5 in comparison with older versions) while comparing it with older versions that change the way we program as much considerable as it worth learning iOS development from scratch with iOS learning materials instead of focusing on old (good) learning resources?
- What tutorial book(s) do you recommend as starting point for iOS programming?

I saw this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming

But as it seems, it has been asked 2 years ago and has not been updated since a couple of months ago and clearly does not even cover iOS 5 learning resources.

Comment: The iOS 6 SDK was released less than half a year ago. There aren't any books written to specifically address it yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Dear Josh, What I was mainly concerned about is that there would be major changes in iOS 6 that require rethinking about some previously introduced concepts as like what happened since introducing collections framework in Java SE5 or after LINQ was introduced in c# 3.5. That is why I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bigger jump from iOS4 to 5 than from 5 to 6 for most kinds of programming (for example ARC).  The biggest thing I've hit is that [UIViewController viewDidUnload:] is now deprecated and you should put clean up code in dealloc.  But generally everything still works the same way for 95% of your code.

My iOS 5 code was recompiled to iOS 6 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, getting started any introductory book will suffice.  You won't need the very latest iOS 6 flavors of tutorials to start learning.

Read the Apple documentation to get started: [Apple Developer Portal](http://developer.apple.com/)

Try some tutorials at: [Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com)

You will learn the fastest by doing.  So, just come up with some small projects on your own, and try to find resources online to complete them

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you first get in touch with 'Programming in Objective-C' book by **Stephen G.Kochan**,and if you want quick learning  then go with either **Lynda iOS 6  essential** tutorial or **head first** iPhone development book 3rd Edition (os6).
If you want strong learning start with **Stanford university**  iPhone videos(2013 winter) from iTunes U and do the assignments .